# Excel VBA "out of memory error" after processing 5048 records

Tags: excel, vba

I'm processing a file that has 34 worksheets, each with a listObject in them and anything from 200 records to ~ 4000 records in each listObject.

So I wrote this program and get an Out of memory error after processing just 5048 records (about 6 worksheets )

I have tried several things

Here's my code:

```
Public Sub importdata()

Dim wb As New Workbook
Dim wks As New Worksheet
Dim wksFinal As New Worksheet
Dim oTbl As ListObject
Dim cl As Range
Dim rw As ListRow
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim dblResult As Double
Dim str3 As String
Dim i As Integer
    
Set wb = Application.Workbooks("WorkbokImworkingOn.xlsx")

Set wksFinal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

i = 2
    
Set wks = wb.Worksheets(1)

For Each wks In wb.Worksheets
    str1 = wks.Name
    
    For Each oTbl In wks.ListObjects
        
        oTbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        For Each rw In oTbl.ListRows
            str2 = rw.Range(1, 1)
            dblResult = rw.Range(1, 2)
            str3 = rw.Range(1, 3)
            wksFinal.Cells(i, 2).Value = str1
            wksFinal.Cells(i, 3).Value = str2
            wksFinal.Cells(i, 4).Value = dblREsult
            wksFinal.Cells(i, 5).Value = str3
            i = i + 1
            If i Mod 5000 = 0 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Save
            End If
            
        Next rw
        Set rw = Nothing
    Next oTbl
    Set oTbl = Nothing
    wb.Save
Next wks

Set wks = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have tried saving the file every 5000 records and setting the objects to Nothing once the With cycle is done. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Seems like a lot of hassle and inefficient to loop row-by-row instead of copying the entire list columns.

Comment: not the issue, but i should be `Long` !

Comment: After `Set wks = wb.Worksheets(1)`, what do you expect from `For Each wks In wb.Worksheets`. To be more sheets(1) in that workbook? And why declaring all worksheets as `New`?

Comment: and you define 3 times wks, with different targets

Comment: @BigBen I do some validations on the data that were not really relevant for the program .

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I did that because without the second target I received a weird message regarding the initialization of the object wks.

Comment: @FaneDuru I guess that was just a force of habit, I'll change that and see if anything is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the problem, the listObject in the seventh worksheet had about a million empty rows, I delete the rows that are empty and the program works.

Thank you for your responses :) I was able to make the program a bit more efficient.